# Не получается попасть на локальный сайт через телефон

Tags: javascript, mysql, сервер, site

Проблема:
Поставил сервер LAMP на Ubuntu(22.04.3 LTS). Настройка стандартная, ничего не менял.
Запустил сервер. С других ноутбуков зайти получается, а с телефона никак. Хотя все в одной сети. Правда,когда-то всё работало, заходить получалось, потом что-то случилось и всё.
Теперь выдаёт ошибку в браузере(Chrome): Не удаётся получить доступ к сайту. Сайт http://ip_addres_notebook/ недоступен ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

Что пробовал:
Переустанавливал ОС , сервер,пробовал другой браузер - ничего не помогло

Мысли: возможно виноват firewall на телефоне, но как отключить его я хз

Помогите......

Comment: Скорее на роутере.

Comment: Возможно, но тогда почему другие ноутбуки он пропускает , а телефон нет, но спасибо за идею.